# Godot Engine Input Map

Tags: settings, godot

so i have been following this tutorial to get me started on a game creation engine on Godot. link here ==> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mc13Z2gboEk and i've got to a point around the time 37:09 and then he told me to click "project settings", then "input map", go on to the action bar and type in "move_left" to create a function for me to move left and click "add". so I did exactly what he told me to except from one problem: nothing happened. it just cleared the action bar, i scrolled down, and there was nothing. i tried again and again, but nothing happened still. I tried putting in "ui_left" (which was already there) for a test and it said that it "already existed" so that confirmed my theory that it did not add to the input map. has anybody experienced this before and if so how do i fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Be more specific about the question.

Comment: What version of Godot is it? I can't reproduce this on the current stable version.

Answer (score 1):

it adds the new inputs to the bottom of the list. if they're not there and you're certain you're doing it exactly right (it's extremely easy to *think* you're doing it exactly right but just miss one thing) then you might want to uninstall/reinstall godot and see if it's just a weird bug/error from your install.